# ambiguous overloaded function reference

Tags: c++

Can someone help me understand why these 2 function calls are ambiguous:

```
int             greater(int i, int j)           { return ( i > j ? i : j); }
double          greater(double x, double y)     { return ( x > y ? x : y); }

int main(){
int          i = 10,         j = 5;
double       x = 7.7,        y = 14.5;
cout << greater(i, j);
cout << greater(x, y);
}
```

The exact error from g++ is:

```
reference to ‘greater’ is ambiguous cout << greater(i, j);
```

This is from Prof. Pohl's excellent book on C++ for C Programmers. I'm compiling with g++ (GCC) 4.9.2.
thank you,
Mainecat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your usage, those two functions are **not** ambiguous.

You're getting an error because of this (assumed) line:

```
using namespace std;
```

This line makes your function ambiguous because `std::greater` is now a candidate.

[Avoid `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way.